# run tasks after grunt concurrent / nodemon

Tags: gruntjs, protractor

I am trying to run protractor tests via grunt.

First attempt:

```
grunt 'test' task : ['nodemon:test', 'protractor-webdriver', 'protractor']
```

This failed because nothing is being run after a nodemon task. I tried a simple mkdir task, but that ran only the nodemon task and stopped using ctrl + c;

Second attempt:

```
grunt 'test' task : ['concurrent:test']
concurrent 'test' task : ['nodemon:test', 'protractor-webdriver', 'protractor']
```

This failed because protractor was trying to run even before protractor-webdriver was started

Third attempt:

```
grunt 'test' task : ['concurrent:server', 'concurrent:test]
concurrent 'server' task : ['nodemon:test'] 
concurrent 'test' task : ['protractor-webdriver', 'protractor']
```

This failed because nothing seems to be run after concurrent:server because it runs nodemon.

**What I want to do:**

Run Nodemon. (or just node if that can run, and pass on control)

When this is done, run Protractor Webdriver.

When this is done, run Protractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [grunt-express-server](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-express-server) instead of nodemon.

Grunt express server is built to give the control back to the following grunt tasks after the server is confirmed to be running by looking for console.log message from the server.

In this way, you will be able to run tasks after starting the server.